# Xamarin Forms set margins through a setter

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set margins programmatically based on the data. I have used a converter for to achieve this. It works great to set the background color but I can't find how to do it to set the margin.

This is my code:

```
private void SetStyles()
        {
            Style incomingMessageStyle = new Style(typeof(Frame))
            {
                Setters = {
                    new Setter { Property = VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.FromRgb(221, 221, 221) },
                    new Setter { Property = Margin, Value = "10,10,80,0"} //MARGIN IS NOT FOUND!
                }
            };
            Resources.Add("IncomingMessageStyle", incomingMessageStyle);

            Style outgoingMessageStyle = new Style(typeof(Frame))
            {
                Setters = {
                    new Setter { Property = VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Color.FromRgb(178, 226, 129) },
                    new Setter { Property = Margin, Value = "10,10,0,80"} //HOW TO SET THE MARGIN HERE?
                }
            };
            Resources.Add("OutgoingMessageStyle", outgoingMessageStyle);
        }
```

Comment: did you try `View.MarginProperty`?

Comment: @Jason I just tried, unfortunately it doesn't work for this particular case

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very helpful description of the problem.  Does it crash?  Do you get an error or exception?  Did you try using a `Thickness` as the value?

Comment: It does work now! The value "10,10,80,0" was incorrect. When I replaced it by for example 10 then the margin is updated programmatically. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
new Setter { Property = View.MarginProperty, Value = new Thickness(...) }
```